# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Tags: angular, rxjs

I got an *ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined* when I navigate to my component. After debugging my code I found where is my error but I don't find a proper way to solve it. Perhaps you can help me?

Below, my .ts file :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-forum-thread',
  templateUrl: './forum-thread.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./forum-thread.component.css']
})
export class ForumThreadComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() theme: Theme;
  threads: Observable<Thread[]>;

constructor(
  private route: ActivatedRoute,
  private location: Location,
  private themeService: ThemeService,
  private threadService: ThreadService
) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.getTheme();
  this.getThreads();
}

getTheme(): void {
  this.themeService.getTheme(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('theme'))
    .subscribe(theme => this.theme = theme);
}

// Error caused by this method..
getThreads(): void {
  this.threads = this.threadService.getThreads(this.theme.id);
}
```

And its corresponding .html file :

```
<div *ngIf="theme">
  <h2>{{ theme.name | uppercase }}</h2>

  <table class="Threads">
     <tr>
       <th>Id</th>
       <th>Date</th>
       <th>Title</th>
       <th>Views</th>
       <th>Thanks</th>
       <th>Comments</th>
     </tr>
     <tr *ngFor="let thread of threads | async">
       <a routerLink="/forum-message/{{theme._id}}/{{thread._id}}">
         <td><span class="badge">{{thread._id}}</span></td>
       </a>
       <td>{{thread.createdAt | date}}</td>
       <td>{{thread.title}}</td>
       <td>{{thread.numberOfViews}}</td>
       <td>{{thread.numberOfThanks}}</td>
       <td>{{thread.numberOfComments}}</td>
     </tr>
   </table>  
 </div>
```

I tried to call again the route snapshot and it worked..
But I don't like the fact to call the route snapshot twice so maybe there is another way?

```
getThreads(): void {
  this.threads = this.threadService.getThreads(
    this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('theme'));
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally changed my code putting `this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('theme');`in a `const` before the call of my functions like this :

```
ngOnInit() {
  const id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('theme');

  this.themeService.getTheme(id)
    .subscribe(theme => {
      this.theme = theme,
      this.getThreadsTheme(theme._id)
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `ngOnInit` block, you are running two functions asynchronously, thus the `theme` lookup in `getThreads` will be undefined. You need to wait until the theme is set.

```
getTheme(): void {
  this.themeService.getTheme(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('theme'))
    .subscribe(theme => {
      this.theme = theme;
      this.getThreads(theme.id);
    });
}
```

And change `getThreads` to:

```
getThreads(themeId): void {
  this.threads = this.threadService.getThreads(themeId);
}
```

Comment: I changed `getThreads()` to take the theme of the subscribe in argument and I don't get the _ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined_ message anymore but I got this one _GET http://localhost:3000/api/threads/undefined 500 (Internal Server Error)_. It seems like the definition is not done before the call of the function.

Comment: I updated the answer to accept the thread id as param instead of lookup on the class.